# Change style of TimePicker in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin, I have added a TimePicker to a Layout. In the preview window it appears as the typical box with arrows above the hour, minute, and time period (AM/PM), but in the emulator and on my phone (Lollipop/Nougat) it appears as a circular analog clock that sets the hands of the clock according to touch input. Is there a way I can force the TimePicker to appear as it does in the preview window? The circular TimePicker is somewhat useless to me.

Comment: Its the native time picker, based on the OS version and style you are running. Time picker is essentially a textbox which opens the native time selection control. If you only need the textbox, then customize the textbox the way you want.

Comment: You can customise by using native renderers

Answer (score 0):

You can update the attribute of the Time Picker in the .axml file to this

```
<TimePicker
...
android:timePickerMode="spinner" />
```

The default value on Material is **clock**.